# How to create a common ext4 [ read / write ] partition with all ubuntu users?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, permissions, ext4, drive

I have a shared EXT4 drive with 777 permissions for all users to use.
Problem is :

```
When a user creates a new folder / file, it gets 644.
I guess that is because of the umask for that user.
```

Now, I want to have all the new content with 777. For that I don't think editing the umask is good idea.

Then I tried the sticky bit, but in case of sticky bit only the user who created that file has the permission to delete the file. Again undesired behavior.

Then I tried, to use acl permissions on that. But on gogoling I got to know that acl is not recursive, therefore the permissions would be lost on 2nd level directory.

please suggest something.. I think i am out of ideas now !

The shared directory is for movies that all are allowed to add and delete. I don't want to go for ntfs - I believe I can have this drive as ext4 with the permission problem solved.

Please help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is commonly solved by adding all users into a group and then using sticky bit in directory's permissions to make sure all files in the directory are owned by that group.

Then the users will have permissions to add/delete files in the directory by virtue of being members of the group.

Comment: Sticky bit will restrict me from deleting other user's files. Without the sticky bit as well the files / folders created are owned by the parent directories group. So, kinda solves the problem.

Comment: @YugalJindle: I'm not sure I can decode your comment :)

Comment: I am not quite sure what Yuga meant either, as if one sets the permissions correctly, all members of the group should have full (rwx) access. Sergey, +1 for a great answer. Yugal, you can also look into bindfs here: http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/ (though that is probably waaay more than what you need).