# I set permission with chmod, but files created later don't have the same permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, transmission

I ran

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /home/thomas/media/
```

But when I make new sub directories with transmission they do not have 777 permission.

Any tips?

Comment: Well my first suggestion is to use a shared location outside home. My second suggestion is to use acl and read up on mask. To give a more specific answer we need more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force permissions on directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740632/force-permissions-on-directory)

Comment: Tons of questions here on shared directories and acl - https://askubuntu.com/questions/202800/how-to-create-a-common-ext4-read-write-partition-with-all-ubuntu-users and https://askubuntu.com/questions/284845/copying-files-and-inherit-permissions-of-target-folder/284849#284849 and on ....

Comment: the answer to the suggested duplicate seems to be specific to Netatalk... It's not clear to me how it would be applied generally since it involves editing a config file belonging to Netatalk

Answer (score 4):

#### Tip #1

Please don't give 777 permissions. There is (I think) *always* a better solution. It's very unsafe to give all permissions (especially write permission) to all users. If you need to grant permissions to specific user(s) or program(s), there are safe ways to do that

#### Tip #2

To set permissions on files that will be created in the future, you can't use `chmod` (although there is a permission bit called set-group-id  (`chmod g+s`) which causes group ownership to be usefully inherited by subdirectories). You use `umask` for that.

#### Tip #3

However, fortunately, there is no `umask` setting so permissive as to grant 777 permission; in fact no `umask` setting will create executable files, for security reasons...

#### Tip #4

... which hints that the `-R` flag to `chmod` is not very useful, since we usually want directories to have execute permission, but we rarely want files to have execute permission. I advise you *not* to use recursive `chmod` unless you know exactly what is in the directory and are sure (ie you are making a well-informed choice) that you want to give those permissions to all of it.

Comment: ACL are the way to go. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/how-do-i-set-up-a-folder-so-that-anything-created-in-it-inherits-permissions and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs and http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2010/03/shared-folders-in-ubuntu-with-setgid.html

Comment: IMO this is not really an answer to the question, more an opinion, listing of problems and limitations, but I will not down vote.

Comment: iam the only user on the local server, used for hobby "work" and education.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen why not downvote if you think it's not an answer? Or you should flag it in that case, no? I am happy to listen to you. I think I read the question as written and answered it, but you are looking for the user's real problem - that's probably the right thing to do, but the question needs to be edited a lot in that case, I think, because as written it says (to paraphrase reasonably I hope) "I tried to chmod -R a directory and files created later didn't have the permissions I set, any tips?" Doesn't it?

Comment: Typically I only down vote answers that I perceive as dangerous or potentially damaging to the system or flat our wrong. I was just adding my 2c and giving some advice.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen maybe I should delete my answer since you voted to close as duplicate? You mention advice and point to good resources, but I don't feel right changing my answer because it's not clear to me what OP *really* wants to do, only that they are currently doing it wrong. So, I would suggest you write a better answer, but if you want to close as duplicate instead maybe my answer is not useful and should be deleted. But if you understand the real problem, in my opinion it would be good to edit the question (then it will be obvious that my answer is not valid)

Comment: I would leave it and I agree one reason I voted to close is the lack of details from the OP.